# Asp.NET CORE: How to increase timeout of request for particular Action/ Controller

Tags: asp.net-core, timeout, executiontimeout

I have a scenario where some particular Controller/ Action take much time to process data. We can increase the timeout period of request at Web.Config as we used to do with vanilla asp.net. This works site wise. Means it will increase timeout for whole site.

We wish to do so for particular controller or action. Can we do this? Do we have any such attribute or any other means to do so?

I could not find any attribute or something yet.

Comment: Depends on your hosting environment. Most common is that a load balancer times out after 2 minutes. More reading if you Google "asp.net core request timeout"

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such attribute which could only increase timeout of request for particular action/controller. All the timeout setting is used for all the requests.